# Visual Studio 2022 - An error occurred while loading the project properties editor

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I recently installed VS 2022 and opened a project I am working on which has been created and worked ok on VS 2019.

When using VS 2022 and trying to access the properties window of the application I get the following error:

```
=====================
09/09/2022 08:18:28
Recoverable
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecutionException: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 9, position 16. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 9, position 16.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(TextReader textReader, LoadOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WindowsForms.MyAppDocument..ctor(DocData docData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WindowsForms.MyAppFileAccessor.<TryGetMyAppFileAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WindowsForms.MyAppFileAccessor.<GetStringPropertyValueAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WindowsForms.MyAppFileAccessor.<GetBooleanPropertyValueAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.WindowsForms.MyAppFileAccessor.<GetEnableVisualStylesAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.ApplicationFrameworkValueProvider.<GetPropertyValueAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.InterceptedProjectProperties.<GetUnevaluatedPropertyValueAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageProperty.<GetUnevaluatedValueFromDataSourceAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.UIPropertyValueDataProducer.<CreateUIPropertyValueValueAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.UIPropertyValueDataProducer.<CreateUIPropertyValueValueAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.UIPropertyValueDataProducer.<CreateUIPropertyValueValuesAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.QueryDataFromProviderStateProducerBase`1.<SendRequestAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<RunQueryOnceAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Start>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<InitializeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<CreateAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertiesEditor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.AsyncLoadContent.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Initialize>b__0>d.MoveNext()
===================
```

I have tried various thing suggested on other threads where users were unable to access the properties of their solution like:

- Disable all extensions, restart VS
- Re-enable all extensions, restart VS
- Remove `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` folder and restart VS
- Once the `%AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` folder got re-created, remove it again and run VS 2022 as administrator
- Instead of right clicking VS 2022 on my taskbar and clicking the project I want to open, I tried opening it directly from the .sln file
- Also tried opening VS 2022 and going to File > Open > Project/Solution and finding my project and opening it this way

None of the above have worked.

Do I need to re-create this project in VS 2022 for this to work or does someone have any knowledge of this error and has resolved it in the past and could share their information?

Comment: This seems like abnormal behavior with Visual Studio.  I would try reinstalling/repairing.

Comment: Luckily I wasn't far into my project so I just re-created it in VS 2022 and actually decided to go from WinForms to WPF for it... still, not sure why this error occurred when trying to open VS 2019 solution in VS 2022.

Comment: Oh! That actually might of been a clue - since it seems to be something XML related, it could have been one of the forms .resx files was messed up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I found this error after converting a .NET Framework WinForms project to .NET 6 WinForms project. I found that the upgrade assistant had added `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` to the project file.

Removing this fixed the issue.